# Using Selenium and XPath, converting a By element to a string

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have a function that takes a By element, By by = By.xpath("xpathString"). Inside my method I am using the following statement to find another WebElement

```
findElement(by).findElements(By.xpath(anotherXPathString))
```

Does anyone know a way to manipulate the first by so I can combine them so I can use one findElement function? I have looked on the Selenium By class page and it has no way to convert a By to a String or to combine to different By elements. My goal is to have it look like

```
By newby = (however we will combine the two by statements);
findElements(newby);
```

or

```
String newXPath = (however we convert the by to a string) + anotherXPathString;
findElements(By.xpath(newXPath));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you know ByChained class?

You can summarize By chain by ByChained use.

see: javadoc (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html)

Hope it helps.